# Инициализация сокетов без библиотек

Tags: mac, ос, gcc, c++, сокет

Добрый вечер.
Я хочу инициализировать сокет на языке С++ (GNU GCC Compiler) (на Mac OS X Lion) без использования сторонних библиотек. Когда я пытаюсь найти информацию в Google, в основном мне предлагают вариант на решения проблемы на WinSock. Скажите, возможно ли инициализировать сокеты без подключения библиотек, самостоятельно. Хотелось бы получить развернутый ответ или ссылку на статью, посвященную этому вопросу.

Answer (score 2):

Не понимаю в чем сложность. Дело в том, что в любой *nix-системе все ф-ции работы с socket'ами присутствуют. И как бы не требуют каких-либо левых библиотек. Т.к. все уже включено из коробки. Посмотрите [такой пример](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm) и [еще здесь](http://citforum.ru/programming/unix/sockets/).

Answer (score 1):

```
man 2 socket 
man 2 connect 
man 2 write 
man 2 read 
man 2 setsockopt 
man 2 getsockopt 
man 2 bind 
man 2 listen 
man 2 accept 
man 2 close 
man 2 shutdown
man 2 ioctl 
man 2 fcntl 
man 2 dup 
man 2 errno 
man 3 perror 
man 3 strerror
```

Предлагаю через встроенный эмулятор терминала медленно раскурить пачку православных(кошерных) manoв и достичь таким образом просветления([вкурИть](http://lurkmore.to/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB)).

Comment: Юмор оценил :-)

Comment: Укороченная версия ответа: RTFM

Comment: Что-то не могу понять толсто это, или тонко :)

Answer (score 1):

[Вот](http://www.ict.edu.ru/ft/004860/net-unix.pdf) pdf-файл, сам его первый раз вижу, но думаю что что-то полезное там есть.

[И здесь](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/146260/) есть много полезного.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, низкоуровневое программирование сокетов  для макосей соответствует POSIX. В таком случае оно описано практически в любой книге по Unix/Linux программированию, в той или иной степени детализации. В качестве самого подробного пособия можно порекомендовать классическую книжку Стивенс "Unix. Разработка сетевых приложений". А так - масса материала в сети и других книжках.

И еще. Если уж совсем хочется отказаться от какой-нибудь зависимости, даже от glibc, то можно писать на ассемблере, осуществляя системные вызовы с помощью специальных инструкций прерываний. Но это уже отдельная тема.